# Shiny - align plots axis

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have a shiny app that have 2 bar charts and one heat chart, they have the same x axis (year),  I want the years to be aligned in all the plots, but I don't know how to do it. below is my UI code:

```
ui = fluidPage(
        titlePanel("Global Terrorism, is it getting worse?"),
            tabsetPanel(
                 tabPanel("Plot", fluid = TRUE,
               sidebarLayout(
                 sidebarPanel(radioButtons(
                        inputId="radio",
                            label="Variable Selection Type:",
                             choices=list(
                              "All Countries",
                              "Select a Country"
                              ),
                         selected="All Countries")


                    ,conditionalPanel(
                        condition = "input.radio != 'All Countries'",
                        selectInput("Country", "Select Country", choices = sort(unique(mydat$Country)), selected = "Iraq"),
                        sliderInput("freq", "Minimum Frequency:",min = 1,  max = 50, value = 15),
                            sliderInput("max", "Maximum Number of Words:", min = 1,  max = 100,  value = 100)
                    ), width=2),

        mainPanel(fluidRow(
            column(8,  plotlyOutput("trendbarPlot", height = "200px",width = 845)),
            column(8,  plotlyOutput("trendheatrPlot", height = "300px",width = 845)),
            column(2,  plotOutput("WordCloud", height = "200px",width = 400)),          
            column(8, plotlyOutput("trendstakbarPlot", height = "200px",width = 895))  
                 )
                 )



               )
      ),
      tabPanel("Map", fluid = TRUE,
               sidebarLayout(
                 sidebarPanel(sliderInput("year", "Select Year:", min = 1968, max = 2009, value = 2009, sep='')),

        mainPanel(
                   htmlOutput("Attacks")
                 )


               )
      )
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Please share your server code with a sample dataset. Without a minimal working example it would be hard to help you out.

Comment: My code is too long, I can't post it in the comment box. can you please advice how I should i provide it.

Comment: You can edit your question and add it there.